# WAS cannot load the EJB interface

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.0

When I deploy my EAR on WAS 6.1 (EAR was built by Jenkins-Ant), and tryy to start the EAR, I get on SystemOut.log:

```
[7/28/13 16:33:18:847 EDT] 00000027 ComponentData E   CWMDF0015E: The class loader cannot load the com.service.ejb.IntegrationServiceRemote interface on the com.service.ejb.IntegrationServiceImpl Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) file
```

The remote interface and the bean implementation have their own jar file and the EAR contains both. I understand the interface should be loaded first, but how to guarantee that? ALso is the error because of the loading order?

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall the Application EAR from the server. Export new EAR from the RAD and install it manually, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The MANIFEST.MF file with the entry IntegrationServiceRemote had a typo. Phew !!

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to click in the paramètrage of publication for WebSphere Application Server of Eclipse IDE "to execute the server and the resources on the server"

and run a server

Answer (score 0):

You might not have mapped the shared library which you have created under the ear file which is deployed. So, go and click on the file you have deployed and under shared library references map the shared library which you have created. Then it will not show this issue.